# What is this seal that looks like a bell?

Tags: united-states, identification, government, assassination, john-f-kennedy

The box on the top left of this picture is stamped with a seal that resembles a bell.  Below is [LOC](https://www.loc.gov/item/2014632047/) photo of the replica of Oswald's gun.

[image: Picture of a replica of Oswald's rifle in front of a stack of boxes]
The stamp is located in the top left.

[image: Closeup of a bell shaped seal.]

[LOC](https://www.loc.gov/item/2014632047/) notes on the photo

> Title, date, and keywords based on information provided by the photographer.
>
> - The rifle is displayed in sixth-floor storeroom of the Texas School Book Depository in Dallas, Texas, where Oswald was perched above Dealey Plaza, when Kennedy, Texas governor John Connally, and their wives rode in an open touring car on Nov. 22, 1963. Now called the Sixth Floor Museum, the site is operated by the Dallas County Historical Foundation. The original rifle and a pistol that Oswald carried that day are now kept out of public view within the National Archives and Records Administration Building in College Park, Maryland.
> - Credit line: The Lyda Hill Texas Collection of Photographs in Carol M. Highsmith's America Project, Library of Congress, Prints and Photographs Division.
> - Gift; The Lyda Hill Foundation; 2014; (DLC/PP-2014:054).
> - Forms part of: Lyda Hill Texas Collection of Photographs in Carol M. Highsmith's America Project in the Carol M. Highsmith Archive.

Comment: This [box stamp](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Box_%28%22Box_A%22%29_Found_on_the_Sixth_Floor_of_the_Texas_School_Book_Depository_Following_the_Assassination_of_President_John_F._Kennedy_-_NARA_-_305160_%28page_1%29.gif) looks *very* similar to yours

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This cardboard box is similar to the one registered as [evidence](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Box_(%22Box_A%22)_Found_on_the_Sixth_Floor_of_the_Texas_School_Book_Depository_Following_the_Assassination_of_President_John_F._Kennedy_-_NARA_-_305160_(page_1).gif) for the investigation of President JF Kennedy's assassination:

[image]

It says: "*Bell Fibre Products Corp.*" and is for "*rolling readers*".

Comment: In the words of Hideo Kojima - "It's a box...just a box."

Comment: The stamp in question will have been applied by the manufacturer of the box; the stamps "TEN ROLLING READERS" and "#15-M" will have been applied by the school book depository or perhaps by the supplier of the books.